# Test sending SQS message from role in Cloud9 having send / received message permission to queue but no message received

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I was using Cloud9 to assume a role to test on the dynamic permission to send message to a queue.

In cloud9, i assumed this role with the following permissions

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sqs:DeleteMessage",
            "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
            "sqs:SendMessage",
            "sqs:GetQueueAttributes"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:{accountID}:general-queue-abc",
            "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:{accountID}:individual-queue-${insert-attribute-by-customer-name}"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sqs:ListQueues",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

After assuming and verifying the right role was assumed, i use cli to send message to the queue, it succeeded with the output

```
{
"MD5OfMessageBody": "dummyNumbers",
"MessageId": "dummyNumbers" }
```

Expected: SQS to show as 1 message received since the message sent request succeeded.

What I saw instead - Number Of Messages Sent increased but no Number Of Messages Received
[image]

But the queue shows message available

[image]

My command

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{AccountID}/individual-queue-{insert-attribute-by-customer-name} --message-body "I am sending a new message...."
```

Question:

- I thought my action was to send a message to SQS queue from Cloud9 after assuming the right permission access, and the queue was supposed to have 'Number of Message Received' since the queue-url i specified the message to send to is the same queue. I am confused with why no 'number of message received' when there's message available shown.
- there is no cloudwatch logs that are able to help me to understand anything
- does this means that the permission actually allows the message sent but there is some issue in the queue receiving the message? (For example access denied?)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have sent 2 messages but haven't received (i.e. read from the queue) any.  Try running the following to receive a message:

```
aws sqs receive-message --queue-url https://sqs.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{AccountID}/individual-queue-{insert-attribute-by-customer-name}
```

Comment: I thought the queue will take it as received message if i send to the queue with the queue url isn't it? My command to send the queue specified the queue-url as the one i took the screenshot above

Comment: I think maybe you're confusing the terminologies.

Send means that the message has been sent to the queue.
Receive means to read the message from the queue.
Delete means to delete the message from the queue.

So when it says 2 messages sent - it means you have sent the 2 messages to the queue (i.e. the queue has received 2 messages from you).

Comment: thanks for clarifying, indeed the definition / naming is confusing